# exportar mi data mysql a un select con optgroup PHP

Tags: php, mysql, array

tengo estas 2 tablas (platos,categorias). y quiero ordenar mis resultados mysql para lograr este resultado:

```html
<select>
<optgroup label="nombre de categoria">
<option>plato de la categoria</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="nombre de categoria 2">
<option>plato de la categoria 2</option>
<option>plato de la categoria 2</option>
<option>plato de la categoria 2</option>
<option>plato de la categoria 2</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="nombre de categoria 3">
<option>plato de la categoria 3</option>
<option>plato de la categoria 3</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

prove con lo siguiente:

guarde mis resultados en un array luego con un for recorri todos esos resultados y los guarde en un array con el indice de la categoria:

```
$platos["id_categoria"]["id_plato"] = array("id_categoria"=>id_categoria,"id_plato"=>id_plato,"nombre_plato"=>nombre_plato);
```

luego recorro todos los array y los vuelvo a ordenar pero me parece demaciado procedimiento para algo tan simple.

codigos mysql php que use:
1: consulta:

```
$query = "
select pla.id_plato,pla.nombre,pla.id_categoria,pla.precio,
cat.nombre as cat_nombre
from platos pla
left join categorias cat on cat.id_categoria = pla.id_categoria
";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez te convenga incluir el orden en que deseas que se obtengan los datos de la consulta, ya sea por categoría, nombre de plato, precio o como lo tengas definido en tu proyecto.

Un formato de arreglo que puede ser útil es:

```
[
  "Categoría 1" => [
    1 => ["Plato 1", "100"], // ID de plato => [Nombre, Precio]
    2 => ["Plato 2", "120"],
    3 => ["Plato 3", "150"],
  ],
  "Categoría 2" => [
    3 => ["Plato 3", "80"],
    4 => ["Plato 4", "75"],
    5 => ["Plato 5", "110"],
  ],
]
```

La representación del arreglo es ya con la estructura que necesitas para armar el *select* y no es tan complicado obtenerlo:

```
// Crear arreglo de todos los platos
$platos = [];
while($row = $funcion_para_extraer_datos($consulta)) {
    // Verificar que existe la categoría:
    if(!isset($platos[$row['cat_nombre']])) {
        // Agregar categoría como arreglo vacío
        $platos[$row['cat_nombre']] = [];
    }
    // Agregar plato en la categoría correspondiente
    $platos[$row['cat_nombre']][$row['id_plato']] = [$row['nombre'], $row['precio']];
}
```

Para generar el *select*:

```
<select name="platos">
<option value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
<?php
// Recorrer categorías
foreach($platos as $cat => $catPlatos) {
    // Crear grupo
    echo "<optgroup label=\"$cat\">\n";
    // Recorrer platos en la categoría
    foreach($catPlatos as $id => $plato) {
        // Agregar precio en dataset,
    // por si necesitas usarlo para realizar cálculos
    echo "<option value=\"$id\" data-precio=\"{$plato[1]}\">{$plato[0]}</option>\n";
    }
    // Cerrar grupo
    echo "</optgroup>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Resultado y un poco de *javascript* agregado para mostrar para qué puede servir tener el precio en cada opción:

```js
// Puedes obtener el precio muy fácil
// Escuchar evento onchange del select
document.querySelector('[name="platos"]').addEventListener('change', function() {
    // selectedIndex es el índice de la opción seleccionada
    let index = this.selectedIndex;
    // Obtener opción actual por índice
    let opc = this.options[index];
    // Verificar que tiene valor
    if(opc.value) {
        // ID de plato es el valor de la opción
        let platoId = opc.value;
        // Nombre es el texto de la opción
        let platoNombre = opc.text;
        // Precio está en atributo de datos
        let platoPrecio = opc.dataset.precio;

        // Ver todos los datos en consola
        console.log(platoId, platoNombre, platoPrecio);
    }
});
```

```html
<select name="platos">
<option value="">-- Selecciona --</option>
<optgroup label="Categoría 1">
<option value="1" data-precio="100">Plato 1</option>
<option value="2" data-precio="120">Plato 2</option>
<option value="3" data-precio="150">Plato 3</option>
</optgroup><optgroup label="Categoría 2">
<option value="3" data-precio="80">Plato 3</option>
<option value="4" data-precio="75">Plato 4</option>
<option value="5" data-precio="110">Plato 5</option>
</optgroup></select>
```

Probablemente me extendí y me salí un poco del tema de la pregunta, pero creo que esta información te puede ser útil para realizar acciones dentro de la página sin tener que recargar.

Comment: Esta es la solucion, gracias amigo, si tan solo ubiera mas gente como tu con esos animos de ayudar a otros colegas.
Bendiciones